# Eclipse m2e: Delete default archetype catalogs

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, maven-archetype

Eclipse offers standard archetype catalogs (Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes) which I want to remove (e.g. because MavenCentral is not available inside the company and the others are not relevant).

The standard archetype catalogs do not allow you to press "Remove". Is there any other way to erase them?